# What is RTW_CMD_THREAD responsible for?

Tags: linux, process, debian, dbus, raspbian

I have a raspbian kernel trace, and somehow the
process "RTW_CMD_THREAD" interrupts my dbus-daemon.

I couldn't find any good explanation on Google

Do you have any idea what this process does?

Answer (score 8):

`RT` - Realtek

`W_CMD` - Write command

`THREAD` - Thread (not a process)

Looking at the [code](http://lxr.oss.org.cn/source/drivers/staging/rtl8188eu/core/rtw_cmd.c#L316) it appears to be a thread responsible for writing commands to Realtek-based network devices.